# How to convert column double into Hadoop in hive database?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using hive-2.1. I have a source system of column cust_id as double, and my hive cust_id data type as bigint. Converting the data, I am not getting current number. I.e.

```
hive> select cast(**2343424324323242322** as double);

**2.3434243243232425E18**

hive> select cast(cast(2343424324323242322 as double) as bigint);

**2343424324323242496**
```

What is the reason, how could I fix it?

Comment: if more then 16 number this problem is getting if less then 16 not a issue with conversion

Comment: Getting through [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) checklist could improve your posts a lot.